# how to compare two dates in java in a simple way

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a simple way to compare two dates of this format for example :

`Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:31:51`

`Mon, 05 Aug 2013 10:18:24`

and display the greatest date?

Comment: Are the dates `String`s or `Date`s?

Comment: [Date.compareTo(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date))

Comment: Have you tried looking at java documentation first? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29 @soulcheck damn you writing faster :D

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you to use **Joda** library. Using the date info you have, create `DateTime` instances and call `isBefore()` method to determine which one comes first.

Comment: Why would someone needs vendor for this while `Date` class has before() and after() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29

Comment: Whilst Joda is a good suggestion, I think the issues presented in this question are more fundamental

Comment: @elbek Ok, you can handle it with Date API. What if the OP comes tomorrow and asks about how long one date is earlier or after than the other one? Can your 'Date' help here? So take a look at Joda.

Answer (score 6):

I would check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), which shows that Date implements `Comparable<Date>` and so

```
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

will do what you want. You may wish to ensure that `date1` is not null.

If your dates are (in fact) Strings, then use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)'s `parse()` method to convert from strings to dates, and then perform that comparison.

As others have suggested, Joda is a better date/time library (better API and threading performance).

Answer (score 3):

`Date d1, d2;` 
This returns greatest dates:
[`d1.after(d2) ? d1 : d2;`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date))

Answer (score 2):

first parse the string into a Date object using a SimpleDateFormat :

```
String dateStringA = "Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:31:51";
String dateStringB = "Mon, 05 Aug 2013 10:18:24";
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date dateA = parserSDF.parse(dateStringA);
Date dateB = parserSDF.parse(dateStringB);
if (dateA.compareTo(dateB) > 0) {
    System.out.println("A bigger");
}
```

then compare the Date objects using compareTo method

Comment: fixed for completeness

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date's getTime() method and then use < >.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
  DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1=df.parse("Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:31:51");
    Date date2=df.parse("Mon, 05 Aug 2013 10:18:24");
    System.out.println(date1.after(date2) ? date1 : date2);
```